# Share Page to Facebook with dynamic meta data

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook share button on my page with will basically open a window and allow the user to share the page...pretty basic stuff. My issue is I want the image and title to be specific to which button was clicked.

So I built a little js component which will update the OG meta tags and with the new content. It will then open the share modal allowing the user to share the page with the new meta info.

Everything works fine for updating the meta informations and opening the modal but the facebook post will still always show the original meta information. My fear is either Facebook is caching the meta data from an earlier period of time or it only accepts the meta data from the initial render of the page. So if anyone has more knowledge on this type of stuff that would be great!... or has done this type of thing before.

My JS component looks like this:

```
'use strict';
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

function updateMetaInformation () {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('a[share-social]');

    if (!buttons) {
        return false;
    }

    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        const href    = button.getAttribute('href');
        const network = button.getAttribute('share-social');
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (network) {
                setCustomMetaData(button)
                .then(() => setTimeout(window.open(href, 'popUpWindow', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'), 2000))
                .then(() => setTimeout(() => resetCustomMetaData(), 2000));
            }
        });

    });
}

function setCustomMetaData (button) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
          const newFacebookTitle = button.getAttribute('data-facebook-title');
          const newTwitterTitle  = button.getAttribute('data-twitter-title');
          const image            = button.getAttribute('data-image');

          const facebookTitle = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');
          const facebookImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
          const twitterTitle  = document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]');
          const twitterImage  = document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]');

          facebookTitle.setAttribute('content', newFacebookTitle);
          twitterTitle.setAttribute('content', newTwitterTitle);
          facebookImage.setAttribute('content', image);
          twitterImage.setAttribute('content', image);

           resolve(button);
       }
   );
}

function resetCustomMetaData () {
    const facebookTitle = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');
    const facebookImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
    const twitterTitle  = document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]');
    const twitterImage  = document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]');

    const originalFacebookTitle = facebookTitle.getAttribute('original');
    const originalFacebookImage = facebookImage.getAttribute('original');
    const originalTwitterTitle  = twitterTitle.getAttribute('original');
    const originalTwitterImage  = twitterImage.getAttribute('original');

    facebookTitle.setAttribute('content', originalFacebookTitle);
    facebookImage.setAttribute('content', originalFacebookImage);
    twitterTitle.setAttribute('content', originalTwitterTitle);
    twitterImage.setAttribute('content', originalTwitterImage);
}

export default updateMetaInformation;
```

As you can see all it does is update the meta tags then after a short delay open the share window.

Comment: Facebook doesn't execute Javascript. Facebook will just take the URL that you share and scrape that one

Comment: ok that is helpful knowledge, thank you. Even if you use something like the npm package for sharing?

Comment: Facebook doesn't execute Javascript. So how you serve the Javascript doesn't matter. You would have to do it on the server

Comment: ahhh darn, thanks for the help! saved me lots of time trying to fix something that was never going to work